# Caddy: unrecognized directive: uri

Tags: caddy, caddyfile

Caddy gives me this error:

> run: adapting config using caddyfile: /etc/caddy/Caddyfile:21: unrecognized directive: uri

My Caddyfile:

```
{
  email localemail@example.com
  acme_ca https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
  #acme_ca https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
}

https://www.example.com {
  file_server {
    root /var/www/html
  }
  try_files {path}.html {path}
  encode gzip zstd
  log
}

example.com, altexample.com, www.altexample.com {
  redir https://www.commerceowl.com{uri}
}

https://help.example.com {
  uri /en/* strip_prefix /en
  redir https://www.commerceowl.com/support{uri}
}
```

What's wrong with `uri /en/* strip_prefix /en`?

Answer (score 1):

Version 2 official document (https://caddyserver.com/docs/caddyfile/directives/uri) describe like this:

> uri strip_prefix /en

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).